# Specify separator for JSON in Go

Tags: json, go

I want custom separators for JSON in Go, equivalent to Python's:

```
json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',',':'))
```

How to specify separator for JSON in Go ?

**Clarification**:

```
json.dumps({"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}, separators=('__','..'))

'{"key2".."value2"__"key1".."value1"}'
```

There are some valid use cases for this requirement:

```
http://mens.com?&cyclone_data={"VisitorId":"53905341bd05ae26a9000001","CampaignId":"538f278cbd05ae36c6000001","LandingPageId":"538eac3ebd05ae15fe000001","OfferId":"538f097ebd05ae2a4d000001","SourceId":"538f0e39bd05ae2b9c000002","NetworkId":""}
```

I need to set this same url in cookie:

```
tracking_data=http://mens.com?&cyclone_data={"VisitorId":"53905341bd05ae26a9000001","CampaignId":"538f278cbd05ae36c6000001","LandingPageId":"538eac3ebd05ae15fe000001","OfferId":"538f097ebd05ae2a4d000001","SourceId":"538f0e39bd05ae2b9c000002","NetworkId":""}
```

After setting cookie with `http.SetCookie()`, Chrome Web Developer tool shows:

```
Date:Thu, 05 Jun 2014 11:23:46 GMT
Location:http://mens.com?&cyclone_data={"VisitorId":"53905341bd05ae26a9000001","CampaignId":"538f278cbd05ae36c6000001","LandingPageId":"538eac3ebd05ae15fe000001","OfferId":"538f097ebd05ae2a4d000001","SourceId":"538f0e39bd05ae2b9c000002","NetworkId":""}
Set-Cookie:538f278cbd05ae36c6000001=538f278cbd05ae36c6000001; Path=/
Set-Cookie:cyclone-track-url=http://mens.com?&cyclone_data={VisitorId:53905341bd05ae26a9000001CampaignId:538f278cbd05ae36c6000001LandingPageId:538eac3ebd05ae15fe000001OfferId:538f097ebd05ae2a4d000001SourceId:538f0e39bd05ae2b9c000002NetworkId:} Content-Length:378
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

`,` and `""` are missing.

I am aware of `base64`. I want users to be able to change `VisitorId` without any manual encode/decode routine.

Server side app reads and compares this url from Cookie and Browser Referer.

**Found this issue:**
https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=7243

Comment: That's a bold user name!

Comment: I hope it won't flame anyone.

Comment: I never pay attention to user names here anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't directly, but if what you want is as I'm guessing to remove extra unneeded spaces, you can use `json.Compact`:

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Compact

It just takes your encoded json and removes unnecessary spaces.

You can also try playing with the `json.MarshalIndent` method, that lets you control indentation separators. But AFAIK, you can't specify non standard separators.

Comment: @GoLangMaster well then the answer is it's not possible, I'm afraid. I also looked at the simplejson wrapper for Go someone made and it doesn't support it as well. Your only option I suppose is to fork the default json module and add the separators option. Out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to pass it as single url parameter without browser encoding my JSON separators for the sake of readability.

Comment: @GoLangMaster I'd just use a browser extension that lets you view the parameters properly. I'm using this one for example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo and there are many others.

Comment: Thanks for extension recommendation. Its very helpful. I updated my question again.